# Integer or int in Processing?

Tags: processing

When I'm creating an integer variable in Processing, should I use `int` or `Integer`? They both seem to work the same way. Is it optional which one you would use?

```
// The same thing?
int     a = 5;
Integer b = 4;

// I prefer Integer because it looks like String:
Integer c = 95;
String  d = "Hello!";

// Then again, int looks like char:
int  e = 3;
char f = 'a';
```

I'm thinking it's probably just what one prefers, though `int` is used more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have different uses. `int` is a primitive type while `Integer` is an object.

The primitive `int` has a default value of *0* while an `Integer` will default to *null*. Primitives use much less memory, just one location of memory, taking up 32 or 64 bits. An object requires more overhead.

Stick to using an `int` unless you have a need for a *null* integer or some other requirement.

For reference:
https://processing.org/reference/int.html
https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/

Answer (score 1):

The `int` type is a **primitive** data type. That means you can use it in any place you can use a **primitive literal**, which you can think of as a typed-out number, like 1, 2, 3, 99, -15, etc.

However, you can't use an int in places you have to use an Object. For example, this code will not compile:

```
void setup(){
  ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
}
```

This code won't compile, because the generic arguments require a class, and int is a primitive, not a class. So how do we get an ArrayList of ints?

That's where **primitive wrapper Objects** come into play. They are Objects  that **wrap** a primitive, such as int. That way you can correct the above code:

```
void setup(){
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Other primitive wrapper classes include Float, Boolean, **Character**, etc.

However, it gets more complicated thanks to **auto-boxing** and **auto-unboxing**. Basically, Java (and therefore Processing) will **automatically convert** between primitive values and their primitive wrapper classes. That's why you can do stuff like this:

```
void setup(){
  int primitive = 7;
  Integer wrapper = 7;

  println(primitive == wrapper);
}
```

So, for your purposes, **it probably doesn't matter which one you use** because Java (and therefore Processing) will automatically convert it for you.

However, using Integer instead of int might create Objects that you don't really need, and more importantly, it might prevent you from using Processing.js mode.

Recommended reading:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have the other selected because I simply think it will be less confusing for beginners but this is definitely good to read too! :)